# Let $a,b$ be relative integers such that $2a+3b$ is divisible by $11$. Prove that $a^2-5b^2$ is also divisible by $11$.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, divisibility

The divisibility for $11$ of $a^2 - 5b^2$ can be easily verified; in fact: $$a \equiv \frac {-3}{2}b \pmod {11}$$ therefore $$\frac {9}{4}\cdot b^2 - 5b^2 = 11(-\frac{b^2}{4}) \equiv 0 \pmod {11}.$$

The solution doesn't need the use of the rules of modular-arithmetic. How can I demonstrate it?

Comment: @Fermat Fractions in modular numbers (in primes) is well defined and understood.  $x^{-1}$ is defined as the value $y$ such that $xy \equiv 1 \pmod p$, or in this case $$-\frac{3}{2} \equiv -3\cdot 6 \equiv 4 \pmod {11}$$ Really I think the provided proof above is fine.  $$a \equiv 4 b \implies a^2 - 4b^2 \equiv 16b^2 - 4b^2 \equiv 11b^2 \equiv 0 \pmod {11}$$

Comment: Yes, you are right... but before using terms like $b^2/4$ we must be sure that $b$ is even and this fraction is an integer...

Comment: @Fermat No you don't.  $b$ isn't an integer.  $b$ is a value from a finite field of 11 possible values.  There is no odd or even in these fields.  $$\frac 12 \equiv 6 \pmod {11}$$ because $$2 \times 6 \equiv 1 \pmod {11}$$

Comment: @Fermat The division there is not precisely the same division seen in equalities. $1/a$ mod $n$, sometimes written $a^{-1}$, is defined as $m$ such that $am \equiv 1\pmod{\!n}$

Comment: $a\equiv \frac{-3}{2}b\implies a^2\equiv \left(\frac{-3}{2}\right)^2b^2\equiv \frac{9}{4}b^2\equiv \frac{20}{4}b^2\equiv 5b^2\pmod{\!11}$.

Comment: Yes, since 2 and 11 are relatively prime, $2^{-1}$ exists...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have for some integer $c$ $$2a+3b=11c,$$ and this is equivalent to $$a=\frac{11c-3b}{2}.$$ Now, squaring both sides we get $$a^2=\frac{11^2c^2-66bc+9b^2}{4} $$ and substracting $5b^2$: $$a^2-5b^2=\frac{11^2c^2-66bc-11b^2}{4} $$ $$ a^2-5b^2=11\left(\frac{11c^2-6bc-b^2}{4}\right).\tag{$\star$}$$ Note that the quantity in brackets in the RHS of $(\star)$ is an integer because $11$ and $4$ are coprime, so the numerator of the fraction must be divisible by $4$ in order to make the RHS itself an integer, just as the LHS is.

Comment: Is it somehow obvious that $$\frac{11c^2-6bc-b^2}{4}$$ is an integer?  Otherwise the proof isn't complete.

Comment: @DanielV nice(+1)

Comment: @DanielV If we multiply both sides by $4$, you get $$4(a^2-5b^2)=11(11c^2-6bc-b^2)$$

So, $4|11(11c^2-6bc-b^2)$, since $\gcd(4,11)=1$, then $4|(11c^2-6bc-b^2)$

Comment: @DanielV Not sure if obvious, but thanks for the remark, I'll add that to the answer.

Comment: @Farnight Exactly, thanks.

Comment: @DomenicoVuono See my edit.

Comment: Ok right accepted

Answer (score 2):

$11\mid 3(2a+4b)(2a-4b)-11a^2+11\cdot 2b^2=a^2-5b^2$

Answer (score 1):

My first thought was to think about a difference of squares: $(2a+3b)(2a-3b) = 4a^2 - 9b^2$.  So if $2a+3b$ is divisible by 11, then $4a^2-9b^2$ as well.  And therefore $4a^2-9b^2+11b^2 = 4a^2+2b^2$ is divisible by 11.

That's not what you asked about.  But is there some number $k$ such that if $k(4a^2+2b^2)$ is divisible by 11, then $a^2-5b^2$ is as well?  (Hint: yes.)

Answer (score 1):

We can simplify and rigorize your proof by scaling by $\,4\,$ to clear denominators, yielding

$$2a\equiv -3b\,\overset{\rm square}\Rightarrow\,\color{#c00}{4a^2\equiv 9b^2}\,\Rightarrow\,\color{#c00}4(\color{#c00}{a^2}-5b^2) \equiv \color{#c00}{9b^2}-20b^2 \equiv -11b^2\equiv 0\!\pmod{\!11}\quad $$

---

**Remark** $\ $ In fact your fractional arithmetic can be made rigorous in any ring where $\,2\,$ is invertible, say $\,2c = 1,\,$ so $\, c = 1/2.\,$ Then we can rewrite your proof as follows

$\ 2a = -3b\,\Rightarrow\, a = -3b/2\,\Rightarrow\,a^2-5b^2 = (9/4 -5)b^2 = (9-5\cdot 4)b^2/4 = -11b^2/4,\,$

${\rm i.e.}\,\ \ c = 2^{-1},\,\ a = -3bc\,\Rightarrow\ \ a^2-5b^2  =\ (9c^2 -5)b^2 = (9-5\cdot 4)b^2c^2 = -11b^2 c^2$

This is true mod $\,m\,$ for any *odd* modulus $\, m = 2c-1\,$ since $\,2c\equiv 1\pmod m.\,$ In particular it is true for modulus $\,m = 11,\,$ where $\,-11b^2c^2\equiv 0.\,$

In the same way, arithmetic of fractions whose denominators are all coprime to the modulus can be made rigorous. This universality of fraction arithmetic will become conceptually clearer when one studies localizations (a generalization of the fraction field construction).

Answer (score 1):

My answer will bring nothing new, but perhaps it will make clearer what you call "the rules of modular arithmetic". Since 11 is a prime, **Z**/11**Z** is a field. For any integer x in **Z**, denote by [x] its congruence class modulo 11. Any non zero [x] is invertible in **Z**/11**Z** . The hypothesis is that [2].[a] = - [3].[b]. Squaring the two sides, we get [4].[$a^2$] = [9].[$b^2$] = - [2].[$b^2$] , or  [2].[$a^2$] = - [$b^2$]. Because 2.5 = 10 , the inverse of -[2] is [5] , so finally [$a^2$] = [5].[$b^2$] , as desired .